# How can I render an image on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, erb

I want to render an image after calling a method in my application. Verifying in my rails console the file_path to the image that I want to render I received the following return :

> [23] pry(main)> y.profile_photo.file_path
> => "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6b614514bb24ee97ca27772d6aebbb2f767c04d7/seneca.jpeg"

Obs : y is a user with a role named **driver**

Then in **.erb** file I tried to pass this image to be rendered as :

```
<div> <img src="http:localhost:3000/#{<%=@ride.driver.profile_photo.file_path%>}"></div>
```

But it did not work. How can I render this image? (located at) :

> /rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6b614514bb24ee97ca27772d6aebbb2f767c04d7/seneca.jpeg

[image: That's how it was rendered in the gmail]

Above, That's how it was rendered in the gmail

Answer (score 2):

In rails you can use `image_tag` to render images.

```
<%= image_tag @ride.driver.profile_photo.file_path %>
```

Or you can use html tag and render image in the `src` attribute.

```
 <img src="<%= @ride.driver.profile_photo.file_path %>">
```

You don't have to absolute path to render image src as browser will take of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me! Well, I think we are almost there. Im going to edit my question and post there what I received after try this <img src="<%= @ride.driver.profile_photo.file_path %>"> in my code. PS : after you visualize the image, it is being rendered at gmail platform

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro Yeah please do

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro if you are using it in Gmail. Then localhost won't work in Gmail. You have to use a server to host and serve images.

Comment: Thanks a lot to say why it is not working. This application and driver's profile_photos are hosted at amazon S3. Could you say how can i do to insert the url of a picture in my application ? "https://application.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/..."

Comment: If you are using active storage with s3. Then you can use service_url to get bucket url of the image.

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks a lot